# How do I install the Declarative module for Qt5 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, qt5

In the pro file I have the following line.

```
QT += core gui quick widgets quickwidgets declarative sql
```

When running qmake I get the following error.

```
error: Unknown module(s) in QT: declarative
```

I have installed the **qtdeclarative5-dev** package but when running qmake in QtCreator I still get the above message

Which one do I need install to get the declarative module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching allot I found this article.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html#qtdeclarative-module-in-qt-5 
I had to install the following packages in ubuntu 16.04 to get all the correct modules.

```
sudo apt-get install qtquick1-5-dev qtscript5-dev
```

That sorted the problem out.

Answer (score 1):

Qt 5.0 is compatible only with Qt Creatoe 2.6.1+, so install Qt Creator 2.6.1

Before you start installation lets remove existing version of Qt Creator.
Run following command in terminal

`sudo apt-get autoremove qtcreator`

download appropriate installer from [here](http://www.qt.io/download/#qt-creator)

go to the directory containing installer and run

`chmod 755 qt-creator-linux-*-opensource-2.6.1.bin`

Run the installer

`sudo ./qt-creator-linux-*-opensource-2.6.1.bin`

That's it. if everything goes fine you will be able to use Qt 5.0 with Qt Creator.

Hope this Helps

Comment: I am using QtCreator 3.5.1, so its fine for the Qt5.5.1 I have on ubuntu.
The problem is still there, I need the declarative module on my system, and don't know what package to install.
The line in the pro file is the following.
QT += core gui quick widgets quickwidgets declarative sql
qmake have a problem finding the declarative module.